# R: Collapse values in data.frame into a vector similar to paste(collapse=',')

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

Consider a code and output like this

```
mtcars %>% group_by(gear) %>% summarize(cyls=paste(unique(cyl),collapse=','))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
   gear  cyls
  <dbl> <chr>
1     3 6,8,4
2     4   6,4
3     5 4,8,6
```

For each gear - I am given a "vector" of unique cyls

A user wants to keep results of an operation inside a data.frame (e.g., which age categories for each event are important) but as a vector (for input into another function).

How can the code be rewritten to output not a char but a vector of cyls? Code below fails.

```
mtcars %>% group_by(gear) %>% summarize(cyls=unique(cyl))
```

The "output" shold be a vector type of column and something like

```
gear  cyls
3   c(6,8,4)
4   c(6,4)
5   c(4,8,6)
```

Comment: Do you mean a vector type or a tibble of 1 by either 3 or 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `cyls` a list column like this:

```
my_df <- mtcars %>% group_by(gear) %>% summarize(cyls=list(unique(cyl)))

my_df$cyls[[1]] # boom dbl vectors for each row stored as a list
[1] 6 8 4
```

Comment: same thing, just an extra coercion, no? maybe a little friendlier printing

Comment: `mtcars %>% group_by(gear) %>% summarize(cyls=list(unique(cyl)))%>%as.data.frame()`.Right more friendlier printing.

Answer (score 1):

using base R we can have:

```
(dat=aggregate(cyl~gear,mtcars,unique))
  gear     cyl
1    3 6, 8, 4
2    4    6, 4
3    5 4, 8, 6
```

Where

```
dat$cyl
$`1`
[1] 6 8 4

$`2`
[1] 6 4

$`3`
[1] 4 8 6
```

Using `dplyr` you will have to coerce the final tibble into a dataframe to be able to obtain the same results

Comment: `dat$cyl` is still a list, same as `dplyr`. It's just a different print display

Comment: To add to Nate's comment, dplyr tibbles are also data frames. Do `class` on the result to see.

Comment: True, although the list will not be visual. it will be hidden within dbl

Comment: You can use `print.AsIs` instead of the default `print`

Comment: That's another way too. although you will have to print every now and then in order to visualize the data.